# how to make Qt treat QVariant as UTC timestamp?

Tags: qt, sqlite, time

i have UTC timestamps in my SQLite database. when i try to get one of them with a SELECT QSqlQuery and QSqlQuery::value(), it returns a QVariant. if i do QVariant::toDateTime(), Qt will treat the timestamp as if it's local time but not UTC. how can i get rid off that improper adjustment?

Comment: Could you not grab it as a string then create a timestamp from that?

Comment: both `QVariant::toDateTime()` and `QDateTime::fromString()` treat timestamps as local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset time zone to UTC you can set zero offset with [QDateTime::setOffsetFromUtc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#setOffsetFromUtc).
It will change `QDateTime` object. So it will refer to a different point in time in contrast to `QDateTime::toUTC()` that converts datetime to UTC.

```
QDateTime datetime(qvariant.toDateTime());
datetime.setOffsetFromUtc(0);
```